# Apply substring to axios response

Tags: javascript

I need to get the text between a some strings in my axios response, I have this syntax but is not working, even I tried only pass the response.data value to the res prop? and print the result in console but I got an undefined message only.

Thank you in advance guys.

```js
<script>
    import Axios from 'axios';

    export default {

        data() {
            res: "",
            report: ""
        },

        methods: {
            sendTest() {
                Axios.post('http://server/',JSON.parse(Payload))
                    .then(response => {

                        this.res = response.data

                        this.report = this.substr(
                            this.res.indexOf('<TAG1>') + 1,
                            this.res.indexOf('</TAG1>')
                        )
                        console.log(this.report);
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e.response)
                    });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you got an example of the response that you should get?

Comment: Something like this

<TAG1>Text...</TAG1><TAG2>Text....</TAG2> the response type y text type

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should check if `response.data` is a string.
In case of a string you have to parse your xml data. For that you do:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response.data,"text/xml");
this.res = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("tag")[0].textContent
```

But you have to care for older IE versions. They don't support DOMParser. In case for older browser you have to add:

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
} else {
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
} 
this.res = xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("tag")[0].textContent
```

If your response.data is already a parsed xml you just do:

```
this.res = response.data.getElementByTag("tag")[0].textContent
```